# android - can't compile VLC project with Android Studio

Tags: android, compilation, open-source, vlc

I downloaded the VLC sources from this link: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android and tried to open it in Android Studio 2.1 on Windows 8.

When the project was opened I got a message *'Could not find com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:sdk-manager-plugin:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT'*

Anyone encountered this issue? How to cure it?

**UPDATED:**
Downloaded the required pack to the directory it tried to search in (C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\com)

Now I have *CreateProcess error=2*

Comment: It looks like they are expecting you to build from the command line, using the `compile.sh` script in the repository root.

Comment: if I only new how :D Now in log: 'WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-05-01 17:49:01,686 [8172254]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - CreateProcess error=2' - why radle without g? maybe that's the reason, how to fix it in this case?

Comment: http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile

Answer (score 0):

just annotate it in build.gradle like this(classpath and apply plugin):

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    //classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:sdk-manager-plugin:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT'
}
//apply plugin: 'android-sdk-manager'
```

Comment: just to comment these lines? (I had them uncommented and it didn't work)

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
sh compile.sh
```

before you use Android Studio open the project. sorry for my english.