# How to successfully import vlc for Android source code to Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager, vlc-android

I have downloaded vlc for android sources from here: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/tree/master

I try to import this to Android studio 2.1 in Windows 10 but always this error pops up(Same error in Ubuntu 16):

```
could not find com.jakewharton.sdkmanager-plugin:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.
```

[image]

Also there is this github page: https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin
Couldn't understand what to do with it.
I am new to android studio and banging my head for days without any luck.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36967067/android-cant-compile-vlc-project-with-android-studio